# .htaccess redirect only URLs contain number at end

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect every URLs contain number at end to subdomain :

```
http://example.com/773 to http://blog.example.com/773
```

and not redirect URLs contain strings like this :

```
http://example.com/web or http://example.com/web/shop or http://example.com/about
```

i used this htaccess code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[0-9]
RewriteRule (.*) http://blog.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

but this htaccess code redirect URLs like this :

```
http://example.com/773 to http://blog.example.com/blog/773
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule below will redirect ONLY this sort of URLs only: `http://example.com/773`. If URL will be like `http://example.com/somfolder/773` (with some folder in the path) then nothing will happened.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```